# Youtube Data API returning different results when calling from the client vs. the server (php)

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the YouTube API to find a set of specific channels in a given country.

When I run this API call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC63W4y26EXa7Vleh5Z-5fqw&key=*********************&part=statistics,snippet
```

via the browser it returns the "country" value as part of the "snippet" part as can be seen below.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/wMuzbevD-QOXuqc28mDTsIwApQg\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/9zM43j9wzRZqCnqmk3ULgh-K_JM\"",
   "id": "UC63W4y26EXa7Vleh5Z-5fqw",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Royalce",
    "description": "Hi all! I hope you enjoy the music (mixes) I put on this channel as much as I do! PM me for requests, Subs are always welcome :) !!",
    "customUrl": "bestofchannel",
    "publishedAt": "2014-05-01T15:53:46.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DhTNWzQjfuo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/KirAFaZlcsc/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DhTNWzQjfuo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/KirAFaZlcsc/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DhTNWzQjfuo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/KirAFaZlcsc/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "Royalce",
     "description": "Hi all! I hope you enjoy the music (mixes) I put on this channel as much as I do! PM me for requests, Subs are always welcome :) !!"
    },
    "country": "NL"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "2115236",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "4645",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "22"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

However when I run the same query via PHP using the following code the country value is not returned.

PHP Code:

```
try{
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id, snippet', array(
    'type' => 'channel',
    'maxResults' => 20,
    'topicId' => "/m/032tl",
    'regionCode' => 'DE',
));
}
```

Result:

```
          [1] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/AjgQ_S7-ek2_Hma9-TmMGxRrnU4"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#channel
                            [channelId] => UCK-4JyAcQYBasFAe367on7w
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2009-05-29T00:14:11.000Z
                            [channelId] => UCK-4JyAcQYBasFAe367on7w
                            [title] => RachhLoves
                            [description] => I have a slight obsession with makeup, coffee & cookies. And by slight, I mean massive. This channel is dedicated to testing new makeup, sharing my beauty ...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-zN9sV9wWCls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dxZoEO6k1Tg/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-zN9sV9wWCls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dxZoEO6k1Tg/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-zN9sV9wWCls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dxZoEO6k1Tg/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => RachhLoves
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )
```

Does anyone know why the "snippet" part returns different results for the same resource (youtube "channel") when running the query via the browser or via the server/php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your code.
Your example is showing calls to two different channels.
Second channel has not set there location, so it will not show in the results.

As it was not mandatory, unfortunately not everyone would have set it.

Comment: Thanks, realised this now as well and built in a check to see if country was set by the channel in the first place.